# How to get online meeting ID from API Graph?

Tags: api, graph, meeting-request

I don't know how to get online meeting id to call this endpoint:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/app/onlineMeetings/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/app/onlineMeetings/%7Bid%7D)

I need to list the meeting attendance.
What I'm doing is to start new meet in Microsoft Teams from 'Teams'->'Channel'->'Meeting'. Then I get URL to share it (https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3A01d9ec1XXX%40thread.tacv2/16000XXXXXXXX?context=%7B%22Tid%22%3A%22fa650ac6-7576-XXXXX%22%2C%22Oid%22%3A%2217ce3fc6-c1e5-4XXXX%22%7D)

I think that the meeting ID from this URL is '16000XXXXXXXX', but when I call to the endpoint, the response is '404 Not found'.